# How to specify name for resource annotations in compile time?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Our code has something like this:

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/resource/foo/bar/ONE_QUEUE")
private Queue queue;
```

However, in one deployment scenario the queue annotation should look like this:

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/resource/foo/bar/SECOND_QUEUE")
private Queue queue;
```

I would like to choose the name to use with Maven build profiles.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not the right way to do things. Resources should be added to the *local jndi name* of individual EJBs. This is to separate the jndi name used in the bean code from the *global jndi bindings* set by the bean deployer. The mapping of the bean *local jndi binding* and the *global binding* may be handled via the `ejb-jar.xml` and appserver-specific deployment descriptors.

So, instead, you should declare your `@Resource` (which is equivalent to a  `<resource-ref>` element indicating resource reference name and type) like this:

```
@Resource(name = "jms/queue/aQueue")
private Queue queue;
```

Then, in a appserver-specific deployment descriptor (for GlassFish it's `sun-ejb-jar.xml`, for JBoss it's `jboss.xml`, for WebLogic it's `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`, etc), declare a `<resource-ref>` element indicating the resource reference name and the global jndi binding via the `<jndi-name>` element.

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jms/queue/aQueue</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>resource/foo/bar/ONE_QUEUE</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Once you'll get the whole thing working, it will be easy to variabalize this appserver-specific deployment descriptor using Maven for different environments with profiles and filtering. Just use a property, activate filtering of resources, and set different value in profiles. Something like that:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jms/queue/aQueue</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>${my.jndi.name}</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use maven filtering, although it would feel strange.

[Here](http://www.gxdeveloperweb.com/Blogs/Bram-de-Kruijff/Maven-secrets-filtering-sources.htm) is an article about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do per-bean config, you could use the JBoss Seam functionality for this (see [Seam reference doc](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/jms.html#d0e21358)). I don't know if this is part of Java Dependency Injection specification (JSR-299) (if you worry about vendor independence).

EDIT: Apparently it is part of JSR-299, see [resin's doc about JSR-299](http://caucho.com/resin/doc/resin-ioc.xtp)